# Are there any CSS properties that don't accept 'inherit' as a value?

Tags: css

Pretty straightforward question.  I know the value doesn't work at all on IE6/7, but are there any CSS properties that won't accept inherit as a valid value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `inherit` is accepted as a value for all properties.

**Source:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

Comment: I guess my google fu needs some polishing, thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

No. See the [CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords):

> all properties accept the CSS-wide keywords, which represent value computations common to all CSS properties.
>
> The ‘inherit’ keyword is defined in [CSS21].
>
> The ‘initial’ keyword represents the specified value that is designated as the property's initial value. [CSS3CASCADE]